# Как исправить ошибку в работе с переменной? С#

Tags: c#, wpf

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            double width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / SystemParameters.CaretWidth;
            double height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / SystemParameters.CaretWidth;
            int WidthConvert = (int)width;
            int HeightConvert = (int)height;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{WidthConvert}");
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка в том что WidthConvert не существует в текущем контексте

Comment: Привыкайте сразу не писать свой код в конструкторе формы. Создайте обработчик события `Window.Loaded`, и пишите код туда. Чтобы создать, откройте XAML формы, там где у вас ширина и высота окна задается напишите `Loaded=` и редактор сам предложит вам создать "New event handler", после чего в C# коде он у вас появится `Window_Loaded`, перенесите весь свой код туда.

Answer (score 0):

Может Вам нужно так

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int WidthConvert;  //Переносим сюда

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            double width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / SystemParameters.CaretWidth;
            double height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / SystemParameters.CaretWidth;

            WidthConvert = (int)width;  //Здесь убираем декларацию
            int HeightConvert = (int)height;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{WidthConvert}");
        }
    }
}
```

:)